# What's the sbt command for creating new lagom microservicem in an existing project?

Tags: scala, sbt, lagom

What's the `sbt` command for creating new lagom microservice in an existing project?

I tried to search this question on google as well as separately in lagom documentation, but didn't find any luck. Right now I am using a very long path of creating new folder and manually copying files, and then manually changing the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There's a GitHub issue [lagom/lagom#81](https://github.com/lagom/lagom/issues/81) that discussed it.

In there Fabrice Sznajderman mentions that he's created a scaffolding plugin for Lagom called [Fabszn/scaffolding-plugin-lagom](https://github.com/Fabszn/scaffolding-plugin-lagom). It's been a while, so I am not sure how compatible it is with the current Lagom releases.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, It’s not needed to me but for sure it’ll help people coming here from searching on internet. Although please try to mention that it’s development is inactive since last two years.